# Something like E-M for discriminative models?

Tags: machine-learning, expectation-maximization

E-M provides a way to improve the estimation of a generative model with unannotated data. Is there anything out there that works the same way for discriminative models (e.g. perceptrons)?

For example, consider averaged perceptron tagger. It would be handy to be able to throw the entire Gigaword through some process of unsupervised model improvement.

**EDIT**:

So, I was pleasantly surprised to note that this site has the ambition of dealing with machine learning, but I'm learning by experiment what vocabulary is generic and what is very domain-specific. Apologies.

Consider a sequence classification problem, like part-of-speech tagging or named entity extraction. You can train a generative model (e.g. an HMM). That's a probability model, and you can apply E-M. However, the number of states grows prohibitive if you want to look at many features, and so the fashion tends toward things like CRFs (batch) or Perceptron (online).

For example, [this](https://aclanthology.org/E09-1087/) paper talks about unsupervised learning in for a perceptron POS tagger, but the details are that they add the output of several pre-existing taggers to the training set of their model.

Comment: Unsupervised learning?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you really want to do (what is the model you want to fit) ? If you don't give a real question there won't be a real answer.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the term for the general idea, but can you cite a specific unsupervised method, other than plain self-training, that works in the discriminative arena?

Comment: Like clustering? It creates the decision that well suits data, so it definitely optimizes classification.

Comment: Ok, I admit that now I am also in deep confusion. Probably you could translate some of the document-retrieval jargon.

Comment: Doc retrieval? None of that. However, I can elaborate.

Comment: EM is simply one way of maximizing likelihood when your log-likelihood function involves logs of sums. This can happen when you have latent variables either in unsupervised or unsupervised models. So for instance, if you fit a CRF and assume some of the outputs are unobserved, it would be suitable to use EM. But you could also maximize that (conditional) likelihood by gradient descent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20151223091555/http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.120.3681&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is very interesting, has good results, and is easy to apply to discriminative models.

And the term is semi-supervised learning, not unsupervised learning.

Answer (score 2):

I think semi-supervised methods may be what you are looking for, there is quite a lot of litterature on this in Machine learning.  There is a good [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Semi-Supervised-Learning-Adaptive-Computation-Machine/dp/0262514125) on this topic, which gives a good idea of recent developments in this area.

An E.M.-like algorithm for logistic regression (a discriminative model) is easily implemented as follows:

(i) Train a LR model using only the labelled data.

(ii) Use the LR model to assign labels to the unlabelled data.

(iii) Train a new LR model using both the labelled and unlabelled data (using the predicted labels).

(iv) repeat (ii) and (iii) until convergence is reached (i.e. none of the predicted labels for the unlabelled examples change).

This works quite well for some problems (e.g. text classification), not so well in others.  EM also works well with naieve Bayes.  McLachlan's excellent [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Discriminant-Statistical-Recognition-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471691151) on discriminant analysis also has some material on basic algorithms.

HTH

Comment: would you happen to know a paper (or publicly available resource) where the equivalence of this algorithm to EM is shown? It is quite intuitive that it would be so, but I am having trouble showing it because in EM you would normally have a latent variable that *generates* the observation not the other way around.

Comment: @Chrigi I have edited my post to say "E.M.-like"; I'm note sure it can be derived directly as an E.M. algorithm, machine learning types (including me) are sometimes a bit lose with terminology.  It is easily derived as an E.M. algorithm for e.g. Naive Bayes where there is a full generative model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. For anyone interested, there is a similar discussion on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3wr2qx/how_does_the_em_algorithm_work_for_discriminative/). In the case here, I believe the algorithm will always converge after the second time step (iii) is performed, because then the LR classifier will be optimal for the labelling it created itself.

Comment: As I understand your algorithm, this is **not** an EM algorithm. I believe you are assigning 0,1 labels rather than probabilities, which is the issue. In an EM algorithm, you replace the missing values with their expected value (assuming the expected value appears linearly in the complete log-likelihood) rather than their most likely value. The algorithm you describe sounds more like you are treating missing values as parameters and optimizing, which leads to a less stable estimator.

Comment: @CliffAB Indeed, perhaps it might be better to include each example twice, once with each label and weight each copy in the likelihood according to the probability?  I suspect it would still be only "EM-like".

Comment: Actually I think that may exactly recreate the expected complete likelihood function, meaning it would exactly be an EM algorithm? I'd have to write it down to double check. One issue to be careful about is running into numerical errors (i.e., $p \log(p)$ for really small $p$) but that just takes clever programming